# Verify value of input address

Tags: transactions, address, transaction-verification

Think about a bitcoin transaction:

Inputs: Address1: 2 BTC, Address2: 1 BTC

Output: Address3: 3 BTC

So the value of Address1 is because of two previous transactions where every one of those 2 transactions sent 1 BTC to Address1. How is a full node now be able to verify that the amount of "2" is correct for the transaction?

Answer (score 2):

Transactions don't work like that, so this issue does not arise.

Inputs of a transaction don't specify *addresses*, they specify *previous transactions*; more precisely, a particular output from a previous transaction.  The data included in an input is a transaction ID and an output index.

So in the example you cite, the transaction would have to have *three* inputs: one for each of the two Address1 transctions, and a third for the Address2 transaction.

Comment: Ok, so we can get a step forward. Think about the transaction X with value 2. The input references a transaction and we actually do not know in which block the referenced transaction is. How to prove that value of "2"?

Comment: Edleredge: I know how transactions work, but you did not get my question. Some guys only want to get attention with the minimum amount of time spending in the answer.

Comment: @ErhardDinhobl: Sorry I missed your previous comment.  We have to actually find the referenced transaction in a block (or in the memory pool).  This can be done very efficiently by a standard full node because it creates an index of all validated transactions, mapping a txid hash to the block, and offset within the block, where the transaction itself can be found.